# unable to access external jar class and its methods

Tags: java, android

i have simple  " welcome message " in my java class, Converted this class into jar,

jar file imported in the android application.

Problem:

unable to access the java class in android. please find the error log below.

**Core JAVA Sample**

```
package com.pat.welcome;

public class Welcome {

    public void sendSMS(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to pat, you can reach me any time");    
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.pat.sendonesms;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.pat.welcome.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String MyLog = null;
    Welcome newwelcome;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.v(MyLog, "Activity loaded, call welcome class");
        newwelcome.sendSMS();
        Log.v(MyLog, "Welcome class called");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
11-20 01:22:48.007: I/dalvikvm(1111): Could not find method com.pat.welcome.Welcome.sendSMS, referenced from method com.pat.sendonesms.MainActivity.onCreate
11-20 01:22:48.007: W/dalvikvm(1111): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4616: Lcom/pat/welcome/Welcome;.sendSMS ()V
11-20 01:22:48.018: D/dalvikvm(1111): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0011
11-20 01:22:48.167: V/(1111): Activity loaded, call welcome class
11-20 01:22:48.167: D/AndroidRuntime(1111): Shutting down VM
11-20 01:22:48.167: W/dalvikvm(1111): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
```

if i add jar as per @Halim: instruction, then i getting jar like the below screen shot[image]

i did " add to build path" getting below error

```
Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Importing is not enough. You will have to add it to the classpath.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux : In that case it would give a NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: you are not initializing the Welcome instance any where. may be thats the problem. You have declared it but not initialized it. bw how did you add the jar file into your project ?

Comment: @sayed.jalil: That would only cause a NPE.

Comment: @ Martin, yes it would. Thanks for pointing it out. But still its a problem :) He must be adding the jar file wrong way. it needs adding to the build path i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included this jar into your Android Project? You can do so by right click the Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries

Then you can Add yourJAR from there

Comment: @Bharanikumar. Please check Order and Export tab. Right click the Project->Properties->Java build path->Order and export->Mark the welcome.jar->Move the jar to top of the list...You may want to try to mark the Android Private Libraries as well.

Comment: @Bharanikumar. If you have updated to ADT17. Please check this http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17 And yes don't forget to clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Project/Properties/Java Build Path/Order and Export -- Make sure there's a check in front of Android Dependencies and the support library, if you use it.Mark all checkboxes.Click on Apply and clean the project.

This worked for me.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To add a jar file properly into your project copy it the libs folder of your android application project. You need to add it to the build path as well. You can do that by right clicking the jar inside the libs folder and selecting 'add to build path'.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can add a jar in eclipse by right clicking on the Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the Jar.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

1. Right Click on Project.
2. Go to "Properties"
3. Click "Java Build Path" on left side
4. Click "Order and export" tab
5. Check all dependencies.

[image]